# Cannot correctly use datas I have got from an API, errors : 'data is undefined', nothing show on screen, or 'data.map() is undefined'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-query

I'm new working with apis, I already made a post but I make a new one to clarify my problem.

I'm trying to get posts from dummyapi, here is my code :

```js
import React from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'
import { useQuery } from 'react-query';



export default function Home() {
  function fetcher() {
    
    return axios.get('https://dummyapi.io/data/v1/post', {
      headers : {
        "app-id" : "#####"(i have one dont worry)
      }
    });
  }

  const {isLoading, data} = useQuery('getPosts',() => fetcher())
  // console.log(data)
  

  if(isLoading){
    return (<p>IsLoading...</p>)
  }

  return (
    <div >
        {Object.keys(data.data).map((e) => <p key={e}>{e.id}</p>)}
        
    </div>
  )
}
```

With this code, i can get the datas, but it don't want to display the ids that are in the return, and when i change something it tells me that data is undefined, to help you to help me here is the api response :

```js
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": "60d21b4667d0d8992e610c85",
            "image": "https://img.dummyapi.io/photo-1564694202779-bc908c327862.jpg",
            "likes": 43,
            "tags": [
                "animal",
                "dog",
                "golden retriever"
            ],
            "text": "adult Labrador retriever",
            "publishDate": "2020-05-24T14:53:17.598Z",
            "owner": {
                "id": "60d0fe4f5311236168a109ca",
                "title": "ms",
                "firstName": "Sara",
                "lastName": "Andersen",
                "picture": "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/women/58.jpg"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": "60d21b4967d0d8992e610c90",
            "image": "https://img.dummyapi.io/photo-1510414696678-2415ad8474aa.jpg",
            "likes": 31,
            "tags": [
                "snow",
                "ice",
                "mountain"
            ],
            "text": "ice caves in the wild landscape photo of ice near ...",
            "publishDate": "2020-05-24T07:44:17.738Z",
            "owner": {
                "id": "60d0fe4f5311236168a10a0b",
                "title": "miss",
                "firstName": "Margarita",
                "lastName": "Vicente",
                "picture": "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/med/women/5.jpg"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": "60d21b8667d0d8992e610d3f",
            "image": "https://img.dummyapi.io/photo-1515376721779-7db6951da88d.jpg",
            "likes": 16,
            "tags": [
                "dog",
                "pet",
                "canine"
            ],
            "text": "@adventure.yuki frozen grass short-coated black do...",
            "publishDate": "2020-05-24T05:44:55.297Z",
            "owner": {
                "id": "60d0fe4f5311236168a109ed",
                "title": "miss",
                "firstName": "Kayla",
                "lastName": "Bredesen",
                "picture": "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/med/women/13.jpg"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": "60d21b3a67d0d8992e610c60",
            "image": "https://img.dummyapi.io/photo-1581804928342-4e3405e39c91.jpg",
            "likes": 7,
            "tags": [
                "canine",
                "pet",
                "mammal"
            ],
            "text": "Hiking with my dog in the woods. black labrador re...",
            "publishDate": "2020-05-23T22:56:11.424Z",
            "owner": {
                "id": "60d0fe4f5311236168a109d5",
                "title": "mrs",
                "firstName": "Sibylle",
                "lastName": "Leibold",
                "picture": "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/med/women/89.jpg"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": "60d21bf967d0d8992e610e9b",
            "image": "https://img.dummyapi.io/photo-1574457547512-5b1646994eea.jpg",
            "likes": 28,
            "tags": [
                "dog",
                "human",
                "animal"
            ],
            "text": "Two boys hug their dogs in a leaf pile in the fall...",
            "publishDate": "2020-05-23T18:52:32.613Z",
            "owner": {
                "id": "60d0fe4f5311236168a109f7",
                "title": "mrs",
                "firstName": "Jolanda",
                "lastName": "Lacroix",
                "picture": "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/med/women/32.jpg"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": "60d21b7d67d0d8992e610d25",
            "image": "https://img.dummyapi.io/photo-1498534928137-473daa67f5c4.jpg",
            "likes": 18,
            "tags": [
                "dog",
                "animal",
                "pet"
            ],
            "text": "Bone salt and pepper schnauzer puppy",
            "publishDate": "2020-05-23T14:42:22.808Z",
            "owner": {
                "id": "60d0fe4f5311236168a109e4",
                "title": "mr",
                "firstName": "Pwry",
                "lastName": "Shylyrd",
                "picture": "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/med/men/37.jpg"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": "60d21bd767d0d8992e610e31",
            "image": "https://img.dummyapi.io/photo-1576707064479-3139e7e8aace.jpg",
            "likes": 19,
            "tags": [
                "animal",
                "canine",
                "dog"
            ],
            "text": "Sleeping dogs lie two dogs lying on black textile",
            "publishDate": "2020-05-23T12:55:22.576Z",
            "owner": {
                "id": "60d0fe4f5311236168a10a0f",
                "title": "mr",
                "firstName": "Kaya",
                "lastName": "Basoglu",
                "picture": "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/med/men/59.jpg"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": "60d21baa67d0d8992e610da7",
            "image": "https://img.dummyapi.io/photo-1500879747858-bb1845b61beb.jpg",
            "likes": 242,
            "tags": [
                "dog",
                "animal",
                "golden retriever"
            ],
            "text": "Dog in a forest at sunset dog in forest with sun r...",
            "publishDate": "2020-05-22T22:27:12.912Z",
            "owner": {
                "id": "60d0fe4f5311236168a10a29",
                "title": "ms",
                "firstName": "Vanessa",
                "lastName": "Ramos",
                "picture": "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/med/women/33.jpg"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": "60d21af967d0d8992e610ba1",
            "image": "https://img.dummyapi.io/photo-1568572933382-74d440642117.jpg",
            "likes": 79,
            "tags": [
                "dog",
                "animal",
                "husky"
            ],
            "text": "black and white Husky",
            "publishDate": "2020-05-22T20:05:03.653Z",
            "owner": {
                "id": "60d0fe4f5311236168a109e4",
                "title": "mr",
                "firstName": "Pwry",
                "lastName": "Shylyrd",
                "picture": "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/med/men/37.jpg"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": "60d21aeb67d0d8992e610b79",
            "image": "https://img.dummyapi.io/photo-1579562243430-4732bcb09d91.jpg",
            "likes": 17,
            "tags": [
                "dog",
                "pet",
                "animal"
            ],
            "text": "Milo durmiendo después de un largo día de jugar en...",
            "publishDate": "2020-05-22T07:50:38.093Z",
            "owner": {
                "id": "60d0fe4f5311236168a109ce",
                "title": "mr",
                "firstName": "Rudi",
                "lastName": "Droste",
                "picture": "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/med/men/83.jpg"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": "60d21bad67d0d8992e610daf",
            "image": "https://img.dummyapi.io/photo-1568480541687-16c2f73eea4c.jpg",
            "likes": 12,
            "tags": [
                "dog",
                "beach",
                "shoreline"
            ],
            "text": "Gratitude short-coated tan dog on seashore",
            "publishDate": "2020-05-22T06:33:02.593Z",
            "owner": {
                "id": "60d0fe4f5311236168a109dd",
                "title": "mr",
                "firstName": "Miguel",
                "lastName": "Lima",
                "picture": "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/med/men/31.jpg"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": "60d21bee67d0d8992e610e79",
            "image": "https://img.dummyapi.io/photo-1517884467367-ac2e21e46d0b.jpg",
            "likes": 43,
            "tags": [
                "pet",
                "canine",
                "grey"
            ],
            "text": "@adventure.yuki peekaboo adult short-coated black ...",
            "publishDate": "2020-05-22T03:10:54.820Z",
            "owner": {
                "id": "60d0fe4f5311236168a109e6",
                "title": "miss",
                "firstName": "Milla",
                "lastName": "Pollari",
                "picture": "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/med/women/89.jpg"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": "60d21bd267d0d8992e610e21",
            "image": "https://img.dummyapi.io/photo-1548658146-f142deadf8f7.jpg",
            "likes": 92,
            "tags": [
                "dog",
                "grey",
                "puppy"
            ],
            "text": "front view of black and white puppy sitting on bro...",
            "publishDate": "2020-05-21T22:15:26.266Z",
            "owner": {
                "id": "60d0fe4f5311236168a10a12",
                "title": "mr",
                "firstName": "Kenneth",
                "lastName": "Carter",
                "picture": "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/med/men/40.jpg"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": "60d21b1a67d0d8992e610c05",
            "image": "https://img.dummyapi.io/photo-1535008652995-e95986556e32.jpg",
            "likes": 15,
            "tags": [
                "human",
                "ocean",
                "nature"
            ],
            "text": "Random man walking with his dogs man and dogs on t...",
            "publishDate": "2020-05-21T15:53:26.275Z",
            "owner": {
                "id": "60d0fe4f5311236168a109e7",
                "title": "mr",
                "firstName": "Joey",
                "lastName": "Oliver",
                "picture": "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/med/men/61.jpg"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": "60d21be267d0d8992e610e52",
            "image": "https://img.dummyapi.io/photo-1580734075803-ac9cdb54fb03.jpg",
            "likes": 3,
            "tags": [
                "dog",
                "canine",
                "animal"
            ],
            "text": "Majestic looking dog on a lake white and brown sho...",
            "publishDate": "2020-05-21T15:15:02.703Z",
            "owner": {
                "id": "60d0fe4f5311236168a109e3",
                "title": "mr",
                "firstName": "Vetle",
                "lastName": "Aasland",
                "picture": "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/med/men/97.jpg"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": "60d21b3667d0d8992e610c56",
            "image": "https://img.dummyapi.io/photo-1558556249-076e42967a24.jpg",
            "likes": 27,
            "tags": [
                "dog",
                "animal",
                "canine"
            ],
            "text": "two puppies next to each other",
            "publishDate": "2020-05-21T07:03:58.248Z",
            "owner": {
                "id": "60d0fe4f5311236168a10a1a",
                "title": "mr",
                "firstName": "Vaino",
                "lastName": "Sakala",
                "picture": "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/med/men/56.jpg"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": "60d21b0767d0d8992e610bcf",
            "image": "https://img.dummyapi.io/photo-1556526588-a0bd9b5a42c3.jpg",
            "likes": 54,
            "tags": [
                "canine",
                "dog",
                "pet"
            ],
            "text": "two white dogs",
            "publishDate": "2020-05-21T02:10:33.421Z",
            "owner": {
                "id": "60d0fe4f5311236168a109fa",
                "title": "ms",
                "firstName": "Ann",
                "lastName": "Mason",
                "picture": "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/med/women/18.jpg"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": "60d21afd67d0d8992e610bad",
            "image": "https://img.dummyapi.io/photo-1575495679620-2ff225c75d5a.jpg",
            "likes": 20,
            "tags": [
                "pet",
                "animal",
                "mammal"
            ],
            "text": "A picture of my golden doodle, Yogi Bear white dog",
            "publishDate": "2020-05-20T21:49:33.321Z",
            "owner": {
                "id": "60d0fe4f5311236168a10a2c",
                "title": "mr",
                "firstName": "Toralf",
                "lastName": "Streicher",
                "picture": "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/med/men/80.jpg"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": "60d21b0467d0d8992e610bc5",
            "image": "https://img.dummyapi.io/photo-1549937334-e94f33e69787.jpg",
            "likes": 5,
            "tags": [
                "dog",
                "pet",
                "mammal"
            ],
            "text": "long-coated brown dog",
            "publishDate": "2020-05-20T21:00:40.371Z",
            "owner": {
                "id": "60d0fe4f5311236168a10a0d",
                "title": "mr",
                "firstName": "Lyam",
                "lastName": "Morin",
                "picture": "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/med/men/95.jpg"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": "60d21bf367d0d8992e610e88",
            "image": "https://img.dummyapi.io/photo-1564849444446-f876dcef378e.jpg",
            "likes": 40,
            "tags": [
                "plant",
                "mammal",
                "pet"
            ],
            "text": "A feral cat short-fur gray and orange cat on green...",
            "publishDate": "2020-05-20T18:51:23.478Z",
            "owner": {
                "id": "60d0fe4f5311236168a109f4",
                "title": "mr",
                "firstName": "Benjamin",
                "lastName": "Holland",
                "picture": "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/med/men/58.jpg"
            }
        }
    ],
    "total": 873,
    "page": 0,
    "limit": 20
}
```

How can I map all elements and by example display every posts ids ? where is my error, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
import React from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import { useQuery } from "react-query";

export default function Home() {
  async function fetcher() {
    const res = await axios.get("https://dummyapi.io/data/v1/post", {
      headers: {
        "app-id": "#####",
      },
    });
    return res.data;
  }

  const { isLoading, data } = useQuery("getPosts", () => fetcher());
  // console.log(data)

  if (isLoading) {
    return <p> IsLoading... </p>;
  }

  return (
    <div>
      {data.map((e) => (
        <p key={e}> {e.id} </p>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

You are getting an object from the API, you should access the `data` property and then map over it. Also make the fetcher async.

Comment: it shows me this error in the console and nothing on the screen : "data.data.map is not a function"

Comment: Try making the `fetcher` function `async` and awaiting the axios request.

Comment: Correction this seemed to work thanks !